# What's wrong with my banana tree?

Tags: plant-health, banana

Recently my banana tree is acting strange. Can somebody please help me to tell me what i do wrong?

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4q0l.jpg)

[image]

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: What's the light situation? How about humidity?

Comment: The plant stands 4 meters from two big windows. And i gave him once a week water. I have him since september and he is changing since the end of december.

Comment: There are some white deposits in the second picture,and some black things (insects?) on the stem in the last picture,but its not possible to see what they are clearly - can you manage to add a clearer picture of those areas please?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion for the reason would be nothing more complicated than a pot too small, poor soil and irregular watering. You might like to read up on a feature of the Bahamas called "banana holes" which tend to emphasize that banana plants appreciate room to spread their roots and good rich soil that along with the ability of the hole to catch water then retains water when the open planted species dry out too fast. Then as herbaceous perennials they just look after themselves.

The growing tip looks good, so it is worth re-potting to a suitably larger size, giving it rich soil and keeping it moist.

Is that some kind of a heater behind it?

Comment: thank you :) , no there is no heater behind it. The plant stands 4m away from the radiator. It is always 17 to 21 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Just needs some TLC, you plant looks ok for now, but being in a small pot, dry, and possibly underfed, it just needs some care.
remove the old leaves repot in some shop bought compost- nothing too special and water regularly- and place somewhere with LIGHT! should bounce back within a month, and then think about placing it outside during the summer to charge it up for the winter. Most tropical plants look a bit tired at this time of year- its normal.